# How to get a value from table by index based on capture_multi in Lua

Tags: nginx, lua, capture, lua-table

The following code prints nil values

```
 local reqs = {}
 table.insert(reqs, { url1 })
 table.insert(reqs, { url2 })
 table.insert(reqs, { url3 })
 local resps = { ngx.location.capture_multi(reqs), }
 for i, resp in ipairs(resps) do
    print(resp[1].status)
 end
```

Outputs nil values and then returns.

```
nil
nil
nil
```

However, if use `resp.status` I get all values I expect

```
200
200
400
```

How can I get these same values by index on the table?

Comment: `resp` is inside `resps`, so if you want to to use the index do `resps[1].status`. I am not sure i understand why you want to set the index statically to the first value though, what would be the point of the loop then? though looking at it now you also have `{ ngx.location.capture_multi(reqs), }` the `,` here will prevent you from getting all the values you should only end up with a table containing `1` value

Comment: I take that last bit about `{ ngx.location.capture_multi(reqs), }` resulting in 1 value back, seems that does give you all the values, as long as no value actually follows the `,`

Comment: Thank you. I'm fooled)